# I am trying to create multiple arrays/dictionaries in C# using a for loop

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, dictionary

I am trying to create multiple arrays/dictionaries in C# using a for loop. I can declare them individually, but it's not clean.

Here is my code:

```
string[] names = ["dSSB", "dGEN", "dLYM", "dLUD", "dGGC", "dMAC", "dMMB"];

for (int i = 0; i <= names.Length; i++)
{
    string building = names[i];
    Dictionary<long, int> building = new Dictionary<long, int>();
}
```

I am trying to use the names stored in the names array to iteratively create arrays. Visual Studio doesn't accept "building" as it is already declared. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So you want to determine the names of the local variables based on other data?  That's not possible.  Why does it matter what the variable name is?  What are you _doing_ with the dictionaries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not a way in C# to create dynamically-named local variables.

Perhaps you want a dictionary of dictionaries?

```
string[] names = ["dSSB", "dGEN", "dLYM", "dLUD", "dGGC", "dMAC", "dMMB"];
var buildings = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<long, int>>();

for (int i = 0; i <= names.Length; i++) {
      buildings[names[i]] = new Dictionary<long, int>();
}

//... meanwhile, at the Hall of Justice ...

// reference the dictionary by key string
buildings["dSSB"][1234L] = 5678;
```

Comment: @D Stanley "...meanwhile, at the Hall of Justice ..." hahaha That made me laugh :) Thank you for your answer. I am trying to create a data structure that I can serialize to create a JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this

```
        string[] names = {"dSSB", "dGEN", "dLYM", "dLUD", "dGGC", "dMAC", "dMMB"};
        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<long, int>> buildings = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<long, int>>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= names.Length -1; i++) 
        {
            buildings[names[i]] = new Dictionary<long, int>();
            buildings[names[i]].Add(5L, 55);
        }

        //Here you can get the needed dictionary from the 'parent' dictionary by key
        var neededDictionary = buildings["dSSB"];
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was wondering: why do use "var" instead of "dictionary"? Is there an advantage?

Comment: There isn't an advantage, it is considered a bad practice too, because is less readable. The CLR will resolve the type of the variable on compile time. See more info at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx
P.S. Sorry for the late answer

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply trying to make a dictionary, and put stuff in it:

```
        Dictionary<int, string> buildings = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        string[] names = { "dSSB", "dGEN", "dLYM", "dLUD", "dGGC", "dMAC", "dMMB" };
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            buildings.Add(i, names[i]);
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> building in buildings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(building);
        }
```

Comment: So, "building" is a general variable represent a key?

Comment: No.  I shouldn't have used the var keyword for this example.  "building" is a KeyValuePair.  I think I can fix it.

Comment: "var" can be a frustrating word.  Look it up.  It's shorthand for strongly typing a variable to the type it's being assigned.
var chicken = new Chicken()
is a synonym for
Chicken chicken = new Chicken();